# Related nodes displaying same related data

Tags: nodes, entities

drupal 7, using views and eva.

So i have restaurant nodes and menu nodes, and all menus nodes relate to a restaurant node, now i have a duplicate restaurant node which is just showing an alternative location for the same franchise, how can i reference the menu nodes related to the first restaurant node into the 2nd duplicate one? (which has a seperate nid)

So end result i am looking for, is if node-rest1 is called, it displays the node-rest1 output, followed by the related nodes (currently using eva), and if i open node-rest2 it shows node-rest2 output followed by the related menu nodes from node-rest1.

is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate node with different locations is in question. I would do it using the [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location) module which can add multiple locations to a single node.

> Location Add Another: Allows you to quickly add new locations to a
>   node.

In your case, you can even add many locations to a restaurant node without creating duplicates. The menus nodes can be [entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) to each restaurant node.

Comment: Sithu, Thank you for your reply, I understand that I can do multiple locations per node, however i have gone with a seperate node per restaurant, since not only does location different, but hours or operation, and even possibly running specials, or promotions. Thus a seperate node has been used per restaurant.